# Program Restart

Tags: windows, visual-c++, restart

I have a Program which is written in C++. It is a program which needs to be restarted when network connection is lost ...

I have written program code which is pinging IP and I'm stuck on that ...

Can anybody show me the code for the next step

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Why do you want to restart your Program when network connection is lost? Shouldn't you reopen your network connection?

Comment: there is server and all of the computers are connected in one IP 

when network is lost i want to restart the program ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate program which monitors your program, and starts it if it stops.

Comment: can you write code of that program ??? i tried smt like that and it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote C++, so I'll present this as pseudo code:

```
if (network connection lost)
{
    Process.Start("C:\Program Files\This Program\program.exe");

    // exit this application
}
```

[C++ Process.Start documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326951(v=VS.71).aspx)